# Django Template overriding

Tags: django, django-templates

I was wondering, when using templates in django, I'm able to extend other base templates and override some of the blocks in the base template. so my question is when I override, would the code in the overridden block still get rendered then overridden, or would it never be run and only the new block is rendered?

Example:

**base.html**

```
{% block menu %}
    {% for option in menu %}

       ...Create the menu entries

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock menu %}
```

**extender.html**

```
{% extends base.html %}

{% block menu %}
    ... some other tags
{% endblock menu %}
```

In this case does the original for loop in the base.html run if it gets overridden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the block will be overwritten unless you want to preserve its code in your extended template.

If you want to preserve the original block you can use `{{ block.super }}`

**base.html**

```html
[...]
<body>
    {% block header %}
        base header content
    {% endblock %}
    [...]
</body>
```

**extended.html**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header %}
    {{ block.super }}
    new content added
{% endblock %}
[...]
```

G.

Comment: Nice! block.super is new to me, so to understand from your answer, if the base.html had a time consuming code in the block, it wont run because it is overridden?

Comment: Yes, that's what will happen! the engine ignores (get rid of) the code in your base template, so, if you do something like `{% block header %}{% endblock %}` it will render (and process) an empty string avoiding any loop or overload in the base template

Comment: Thanks @gariel, this is what im looking for.